# How to use nextjs 13.2 builtin server for socket.io?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, websocket, socket.io

I am making a realtime quiz with scoreboard that needs to have a websocket connection in nextjs 13.2 and I am unable to figure out how to host a socket server on for example `/host-quiz` tab will be open with room id and i will give room id to all other users and they will put that in `/start`
route and they will connected to the room and `/scoreboard` will show all the joined users`, but i m unable to figure out how can i use socket.io in nextjs 13.2 with route handlers?

Please help in writing a example server code in typescript for socket connection server and a client page in nextjs (ts) to connect to that builtin server.

Comment: Have you figured this out yet?

Comment: No sir, not yet